# jmeter http request in a while loop is caching the results

Tags: caching, while-loop, jmeter

[image]In JMeter in a while loop I'm sending an http request and storing few json values from the response. In this loop, I'm getting same json value each time the loop is repeated. I have tried

HTTP Cookie Manager

HTTP cache manager

to clear cache. But is there way to clear the cache/RAM during while loop? I need new values to be stored in Response and jsonpath Expression variables.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Either the problem is in the way you store json response or server really returns same response or there's some other test design issue. I can't imagine how else JMeter would "repeat" response. In your case (when you don't want anything to be cached) you don't need HTTP cache manager and since response you want is not cookie, HTTP Cookie Manager won't do much for you either.
So I suggest to share a piece of your jmeter tree here, which includes details on how exactly do you save a response. Also run it with View Response Tree, see what actually happens and show us here as well.

Comment: You are correct. It is actually not caching any results.  The mistake is in my script. Instead of handling a invalid response body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Add `Http Coockie Manager` and `Http Cache Manager` inside  `While Controler`

[image]

Don't forget to check clear cache and clear cookie checkbox in both managers

[image]

Comment: Accepted you answer as you have answered how to clear cache question. It is not relevant in my case. The issue is they way I'm handling my response body. Thanks any way.

Comment: @learningJ The assignment will get a new value in each iteration. So what do you mean by clearing Json values. i. e. if you extract `x` from the response in the first iteration and it has a value like `x1`, in the next iteration the Json extractor will recognize `x2` as the new value for `x`. So the new value would be replaced. Now why you wanna delete the old value?